# convert file name and line number to VS link

Tags: visual-studio

I have a report which contains file names and line numbers.

.e.g.

c:\Foo\bar.cs:42

c:\Foo\bar2.cs:845

I would like to convert these into clickable links so that the file will open to that line number in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I got what I needed by first converting the text file to the msbuild [error format](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2006/11/03/msbuild-visual-studio-aware-error-messages-and-message-formats.aspx):

c:\Foo\bar.cs(42): warning : message

c:\Foo\bar2.cs(845): warning : message

After, I created a new csproj file with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="Build">
    <Exec Command="type errorReport.txt" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Building this solution then generates an error report where I can click the error and have the file open in VS to that line number.